# Plotly Plot Not Showing in Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I am trying to run a plotly example code on my Jupyter Notebook, the code ran successfully, but they would not show the plot and will generate the `'NoneType' object is not callable` error when I tried to show it using `fig.show()`

My Plotly version is 4.14.3, and I have tried both `%matplotlib.notebook` and `%matplotlib.inline`, both failed to show the plot.

The code is listed below, where did it go wrong?

```
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.graph_objs as go

labels = ['Oxygen','Hydrogen','Carbon_Dioxide','Nitrogen']
values = [4500, 2500, 1053, 500]

fig = go.Figure(data= [go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values, textinfo='label+percent')])
fig.show()
```

Comment: That's quite peculiar. Your code works as expected in my Jupyter Notebook with the same version of Plotly. What happens if you restart the notebook and clear the output?

Comment: The error message `'NoneType' object is not callable` is also strange. The only NoneType object would be fig.show(), so unless you are doing something like fig.show()() I don't understand where the error message is coming from

Comment: I have tried restarting my notebook and re-executing the code. The same error occurred. The weird thing is, when I tried to run only ```fig```, then a dict would show up: ```{'type': 'pie', 'labels': ['Oxygen', 'Hydrogen', 'Carbon_Dioxide', 'Nitrogen'],  'values': [4500, 2500, 1053, 500]}```. So apparently fig was created successfully, but somehow it beocmes a ```NoneType``` object when I was trying to display it with a ```show()``` command.